# How to set custom sound?

Tags: java, android

Where I set sound can you help me, please!

I will try to

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.musound);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(uri);
```

But when i send notification my app will be crash

Here logcat report

> Process: com.example.ciyashop, PID: 13336
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
>           at com.example.ciyashop.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService.sendNotification(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:96)
>           at com.example.ciyashop.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:47)

Comment: `context` is `null`.